# Laravel 5.4 Handler.php redirect from Ajax Call

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Im trying to redirect users with "TokenMismatchException" to login page. All my website is based on JQuery, the user never change the main page, only the content, so the problem is that the response from Handler.php about the error will be passed to the jquery functions, but there's tons of functions, i dont want to make an if in all them.

I tried creating a blade with this content:

```
<script>
   window.location.replace('https://brasilbitcoin.com.br/entrar');
</script>
```

And return this blade if error, but doesn't work either...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Return redirect link as a response (with appropriate HTTP status code). Than make redirection on client after your AJAX request is finished. Provide your JS code where you're expecting redirect response to get more help.

Answer (score 0):

inside your **Exceptions/Handler.php**

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
 {

         if ($this->isTokenMismatchException($exception)){
            return redirect('/login');
        } 
 }
```